# How to add the output of a readline inside a for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to code a loop that will find a test average for a certan number of tests that the user defines. I need to add the output/input (the number you type in the console) of all the readlines that run in the loop.

i have made a variation of this project in the past with a set number of test scores you can input but i have no experience adding the readlines in a loop

```
test_no = int(input("How Many Tests Did You Take: "))
for x in range (1, test_no+1):
    t_score = int(input("The Score on Test %s Was: " % x)) 
average = t_score/test_no
print (average)
```

i am expecting the output to have added all the outputs of the readline function inside the loop and ten divided by the number of times the loop runs

Comment: "i am expecting the output to have added all the outputs" - why... are you expecting this? I mean, your code contains only one addition operator in `test_no+1`, and `t_score` gets overwritten on each iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @ForceBrue commented, you are not adding scores, instead overwriting. I guess this is what you want to achieve:

```
test_no = int(input("How Many Tests Did You Take: "))
t_score = 0
for x in range (1, test_no+1):
    t_score += int(input("The Score on Test %s Was: " % x)) 
average = t_score/test_no
print (average)
```